# jQuery version not supported on Android 7.0?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am using a simple [PHP-based file manager system](https://github.com/jcampbell1/simple-file-manager) that [uses jQuery 1.8.2](https://github.com/jcampbell1/simple-file-manager/blob/86df13b3e3ca42c86e66ffe46a26644e21161b05/index.php#L229) on the original code to construct the tables. I can easily open the webpage using any windows browsers, but when I use my android tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 , SM-T710) using Android 7.0, I cannot open the webpage. But when I try to open the webpage using another tablet with same specifications but equipped with Android 6.0.1, I have no problem opening the page with full functionality.

I managed to obtain android log files containing the following error:

```
12-01 17:08:09.453 22534 22534 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(99)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"
```

I know that the problem lies with jQuery version that I am using, but I do not know what versions are being supported by android and how to narrow down the options.

I have tried different browsers and all devices, and the results do not change. It either works on all browsers on the device or none of them. Also tried a couple of jQuery version manually but could not get it to work.

I would appreciate any help on the matter.

Comment: Could it be because of some browser caching?

Comment: I have cleared all browser cache on the devices and checked the webpage again, no changes in results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick fix to the problem.

The original code, as referenced in the original post, uses the following line to include the jQuery library:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But the quick fix that I found to the problem, is to download the jQuery library itself and put it in the folder and include it in the library call line. Hence I downloaded the latest version (3.2.1) from [jQuery Website](http://jquery.com/download/) and changed the above line to the following:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

In this way, I am statically calling the library and including it with the webpage itself. I know it is not efficient in any way, but it fixed my problem and the issue is resolved.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your fix. You can use a local version of a js library whenever you want.

Comment: @nicolascolman Is downloading the js library and using it locally a regular practice? I would think that it would make the system more stable and self-sustaining.

Comment: The best practice is using a package manager (e.g. composer, npm, bower, etc.). It downloads the library and allows you tu use it locally.